# attempt to compare string and number lua

Tags: lua, roblox

```
script.Parent.Yes.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    if game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Stage.Value < 20 and db then
        db = false
        script.Parent.Question.Text = "YOU NEED ATLEAST 20 STAGES TO REBIRTH!"
        wait(3)
        script.Parent.Visible = false
        open = false
        db = true
    elseif db then
        game.ReplicatedStorage.Rebirth:FireServer()
        script.Parent.Visible = false
        open = false
    end
end)
```

why is this showing an error on line 2 saying attempt to compare string and number?

Answer (score 0):

That means game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Stage.Value is a string. I don't know how leaderstats work but I think you've made it a string accidentally instead of a number.